# Using Calendar on react js

Tags: reactjs, calendar, tui-calendar

learning about [ToastUI calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toast-ui/react-calendar) and I'm implement some code, so following the documents I create this code:

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/calendar-w82787?file=/src/calendar.jsx)

so, I just want disable header `Milestone, Task, All Day` so I added this code:

```
          taskView={false}
          scheduleView={["time"]}
```

like props on my `<TUICalendar />`, but didn't work, so please, you can help me, what's wrong? what I'm doing wrong??